# Как связать wpf/c# программу со службой  и привязать grid к  таблицы службы

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, wcf

Как создать службу , передав ей параметры соединения с сервером и что б она периодически занималась обновлением таблиц, а основная программа на c# wpf  ей передавала запросы и брала таблицы. И как забиндить grid из xaml на таблицу этой службы, а служба пусть занимается обработкой данных.

Как такое сделать? wcf и подобным ещё не занимался.

Answer (score 3):

Grid - это View, а если есть View, то должна быть и модель. Я могу предложить примерно следующее решение:

---

- Обойдитесь без "службы". Служба - очень неформальное понятие и слишком общее для паттерн-based программирования.
- Введите у себя в приложении некоторую фабрику моделей, скажем `YYYModelFactory`. Именно эта фабрика будет принимать в себя параметры соединения с БД.
- ПОнятно, что фабрика возвращает некоторую модель, которая уже забиндена на БД. У этой модели вполне разумно ввести методы типа Update и т.п, логика которых локальна для модели. Альтернативно, конечно, можно на каждый запрос типа Update конструировать новую модель, но этот подход в общем случае considered harmful.
- Модель - это некоторая ObservableCollection в терминах MVVM. Значит, нацепить на нее GridView можно совершенно нативным способом (читайте про MVVM, если еще не в курсе). Любое обновление правильно организованной модели **будет автоматически проектироваться** на View, если модель установлена в качестве некоторого BindingElement.

Comment: За что минус?